# HTML 5 chart issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, devextreme

I'm drawing a chart for my web page which i learned from this video 
https://youtu.be/qYkkyOzR9jc
i'm trying to add label to my chart, but it doesn't work and make my chart wrong
here's my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="JS/dx.chartjs.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/13.1.7/js/dx.chartjs.js"> </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/PieChart.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="border: 1px solid red; "></div>

</body>
</html>
```

here's my JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dataSource = [
        { country: "Russia", area: 1707540},
        { country: "Canada", area: 998467},
        { country: "USA", area: 937261},
        { country: "China", area: 959696},
        { country: "Brazil", area: 854700},
        { country: "Australia", area: 768685},
        { country: "India", area: 328759},
        { country: "Others", area: 554545}
    ];

    $("#chartContainer").dxPieChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        series: {
            argumentField: "country",
            valueField: "area",
            label: {
                visible: true,
                connector: {visible: true}
            }

        }
    });

})
```

this is my chart without label
[image]

this is my wrong chart after adding label element
[image]

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: yes.
somethings like this

t.formatHelper._formatNumberCore @ dx.chartjs.js:9

Comment: i think you need the `globalize.js` library too. also, looks like there might be some version compatibility issues amongst globalize, jquery, and dx.chartjs so you might have to do some fiddling to get the right set of versions.

Answer (score 0):

As lispHK01 noticed, you missed a reference to the globalize library. Your html file should look like the following.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/13.1.7/js/dx.chartjs.js"> </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/PieChart.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="border: 1px solid red; "></div>

</body>
</html>
```